# Connecting with Printer from Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

How can we use the print functionality from Apache Nifi? How to connect to printer via NIFI. Please help here.

Just need to read one PDF or Doc file , and print the same from Apache Nifi

Comment: To be clear, when you say Printer, do you mean...printing it out on a piece of paper?

Comment: The nifi process is trying to read data from Text or any file, and print the content (Connecting with printer directly and printing)

Comment: Thanks for checking.  Just need to read one PDF or Doc file , and print the same from Apache Nifi